# Navigate between errors for only CVS changed lines in IntelliJ Idea / PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

It is extremely handy to [navigate between errors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html) (using f2) on IntelliJ Idea / PyCharm.

Is there any way to navigate between errors only for CVS changed lines?

Comment: If your changes caused errors in other parts of the code that wasn't touched by you, what good would that do precisely?...Just curious.

Comment: @Makoto IMO it is better to keep it simple, it could work just like code formatting.

Comment: No, there is no such action in PyCharm. You can write a plugin to add one.